# Create a Installer setup using InnoIde for Framework 4.5 WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf

My team is working on a WPF application. We are using  Visual studio 2012 for development and we are using framework 4.5. Now we are struggling on how to create the setup project. On the way as per requirement ,we tried to use Innoide (http://www.innoide.net/) to create setup.
•   We have created a sample application and configured its primary output file(.exe) through inno IDE wizard for creating setup file
•   Then we have configured Icon, install actions and necessary fields and now we have the following script:

```
![\[Files\]
Source: "C:\Users\Praveen\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\GridChildDemo\GridChildDemo\bin\Debug\GridChildDemo.exe"; DestDir: {app};


\[Icons\]
Name: {group}\; Filename: {app}\GridChildDemo.exe; WorkingDir: {app}; Flags: CreateOnlyIfFileExists;

\[Run\]
Filename: {app}\GridChildDemo.exe; WorkingDir: {app}; Flags: PostInstall NoWait SkipIfSilent;][1]
```

After these steps, tried to press the Compile option, but the generated script is not compiling and shows a not responding window:

[image]

Comment: Is there any reason you avoided the obvious choice of WiX?

Comment: as per requirement,the specifiers suggesting Innoide

Answer (score 0):

just right click on the project you created and select "Publish" this will create the setup file for you using the traditional way,

if you want to make it advance and choose an icon for the setup and stuff liuke that, just right click on the solution > add new item > installation wizard

check out the link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kay7az51(v=vs.71).aspx